# How to have a text output when a formula is true in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to display a letter grade based on a percentage grade. So Say one cell (A1) has a value of 96% and based on A1's value the second cell (A2) would Give an output of "A".

I've tried `=if(ISBETWEEN(A1,90%,100%)=TRUE),,"A"` (this formula would go into cell A2)

and if anyone could help me with having multiple `if` formula statements and putting them in one cell.

- A = 100%-90%
- B = 89%-80%
- C = 79%-70%
- D = 69%-60%
- F = 59%-0%

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {0,"F"; 0.6,"D"; 0.7,"C"; 0.8,"B"; 0.9,"A"}, 2, 1)))
```

Comment: thank you this did work but I did have to change the `1` to `0.9` because it saw 90%-99% as a "B" 

`=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2, {0,"F"; 0.6,"D"; 0.7,"C"; 0.8,"B"; 0.9,"A"}, 2, 1)))
`

Comment: @UFTaco indeed. fixed

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation